# document.ready not working with ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax to load in posts on a WordPress site.

Inside each post I have a hidden div with sharing buttons, which is unhidden with a jquery toggleClass function.

It's really simple.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".sharing-mp").click(function() {       
      $(".sharing-mp").toggleClass('sharing-mp-hidden').toggleClass('sharing-mp-visible');
    });    
});
```

The problem is, it doesn't work on posts that are loaded in with ajax, I guess because they're being appended to the DOM and the .ready function isn't finding them?
Is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use on() to bind click event for dynamically loaded elements. You can delegate the event to parent element to which elements added dynamically or to document otherwise.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(document).on("click", ".sharing-mp", function() {     
         $(".sharing-mp").toggleClass('sharing-mp-hidden').toggleClass('sharing-mp-visible');    
     });    
});
```

Comment: You don't need the `$(document).ready` if you're doing a `$(document).on`

Answer (score 1):

You probably only need one of those classes too.

sharing-mp-hidden and sharing-mp-visible sound like they're simply opposites of each other. So one would have `display: none;` and the other `display:block;`. Instead of 2 classes you could set the default for `sharing-mp` to be `display:block;`

Also, there is are jquery functions for show and hide which do the same thing.

Comment: I'd lose the CSS animations doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use event delegation with `.on()` handler to its parent which was available at the time of page load. This could be the `$(document)` itself because its the parent of all other elements or you could try to delegate the event to its closest available parent which was available at `doc ready` like post holder div or content container etc.

Nonetheless this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '.sharing-mp', function() {       
      $(this).toggleClass('sharing-mp-hidden sharing-mp-visible');
    });    
});
```